# Winpcap listening a device with 2 different filters

Tags: winpcap

Is it doable to listen a device with 2 different filters and capture packets? For example i start listening a device with a filter and dumping the packets to a pcap file, after 15min can i start another listen on the same device with different filter and dump the packets to another pcap file without stopping the old one?

Does pcap_open or pcap_next_ex block the incoming packets? What i mean if a packet arrives while listening from two different threads one of them will get the packet and control it for filter can the other thread access the packet?

I hope im clear sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i start another listen on the same device with different filter and dump the packets to another pcap > file without stopping the old one?

Yes. Albeit, you'd better start that listener in a different thread/process to process it.

> Does pcap_open or pcap_next_ex block the incoming packets?

It does not. It drops the packets to your pcap listener if one part (you or the OS) can't keep up with the incoming packets.

pcap will also duplicate the packets(speaking at least of the *nix pcap, assuming winpcap works the same) so if you have several pcap listners, filtering for the same packets , they will all get a copy.

Answer (score 0):

For each open device handle you get, you have a seperate filter, and packet buffer.
say handle 'A' and handle 'B'
now lets say both handles are on the same network device.

Now lets say that the network device gets 4 packets.

each packet gets to the hardware driver, then to winpcap.
at that point winpcap applys each handles filter one at a time.
if a match is made, the packet will be copied to that handles packet buffer.
after all handles have been processed, the packet is handed off to the OS.

Does pcap_open or pcap_next_ex block the incoming packets? No.

The fact is that the operating system, will most likely see the packet before your application will process it. 
I may be wrong but I don't think winpcap has any standard method for blocking a packet.